# Orchard CMS: N to N relation between ContentItems

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I need to create N to N relation between `ContentItems`. I've read [corresponding article](http://docs.orchardproject.ru/Documentation/Creating-1-n-and-n-n-relations) in documentation. There are 3 types of relations:

1. 1 to N relation between records
2. N to N relation between records
3. 1 to N relation between Content Items with lazy loading.

I haven't found any manual for creating N-to-N relation between content items. I have:

1. `ProfessionItem` with `ProfPart`/`ProfPartRecord`
2. `SpecialityItem` with `SpecPart`/`SpecPartRecord`

So far I've only created N to N between records. I think I should create some kind of record like:

```
public class ContentProfSpecRecord {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ContentItemRecord Spec { get; set; }
    public virtual ContentItemRecord Prof { get; set; }
}
```

but I'm little bit confused with all these `Lazy` fields. Should I add `LazyField<IEnumerable<IContent>>` to `ProfPartRecord` or not?

Any links to guides or any help will be appreciated.
thanks!

Comment: Why not use a content item picker?

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy I currently have about 50 `ProfessionItems` and 80 `SpecialityItems`, specItems count is limited to about 500. so I need custom interface with filtering and so on. I'm not sure `ContentItemPicker` is convenient here

Comment: Yes, it may be, because the content item picker is extensible. Then again, you may not even need to, because it already has search built-in.